# JQuery $.ajax Google Books API using phonegap and jQueryMobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, google-api

How can I make this code work, the problem is that I can't seem to be able to acces the data returned, I know that it connects to the server, but for somereason it wont work, for example, I tried extracting the title but nothing appears.

```
$.ajax({
        url : "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=harry+potter",
        dataType : "jsonp",
        async : true,
        //if ajax call succeeds perform this action
        success : function(result) {
            ajax.parseJSONP(result);
        },
        //if there is an error to the ajax call perform this action
        error : function(request, error) {
            alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
        }
    });
    //parseJsonP and add new elements to list-view 
    var ajax = {
        parseJSONP : function(result) {
            //iterate each returned item 
            $.each(result, function(i, row) {
                $('#listview_test').append('<li><h3>' + row.volumeInfo.title + '</h3></a></li>');
            }); //end iteration of data returned from server and append to the list
            $('#listview_test').listview('refresh'); // refresh the list-view so new elements are added to the DOM
        }
    }
```

My confusion is on the callback method, in their example Books API has a code like is shown down, but I dont get it this part `q=harry+potter&callback=handleResponse`, how can I make this while using the $.ajax method. Tried understanding all the pieces but still very confusing?

```
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script>
      function handleResponse(response) {
      for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
        var item = response.items[i];
        // in production code, item.text should have the HTML entities escaped.
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<br>" + item.volumeInfo.title;
      }
    }
    </script>
    <script src="https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=harry+potter&callback=handleResponse"></script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing your following code:

```
$.each(result, function(i, row) {
```

for this one:

```
$.each(result.items, function(i, row) {
```

As per the google example code the data is located in an array called `items` within the returned object.

Comment: `.each(result.items, function(i, row){
                $('#listview_test').append('<li><h3>' + items.volumeInfo.title + '</h3></a></li>');
            });` Same thing can't see anything... I am using both browser and android emulator to test...

Comment: Just inspect your variable in the chrome inspector with `console.log(result)` to see what carries..

Comment: Also take care with your imbalanced tags `<li><h3>' + row.volumeInfo.title + '</h3></a></li>` your last `</a>` don't have a opening one.

Comment: Oh I see!, you changed your `row.volumeInfo.title` for `items.volumeInfo.title` , don't do that, just change the code I posted in my answer, it should work as is with the rest of your original code.

Comment: Thank you so much, great help. One question, is confusing me so much. How come this is working without providing in the link the `?callback=handleResponse`? and plus Google Books saiz I have to always provide a key, but this is still working without a key?

Comment: jQuery adds automatically the `?callback=whatever` when using the `jsonp` datatype, that's how jsonp works. The google key I don't know I've never used google books api.

Comment: I see I get it now. So how come you knew it is on .items the data if you have never used the API before? Is it possible to add a variable for every image in here `<img src="" ` if I find the appropriate data in the object? In any case thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Because in the google example code you posted, it can be seen `response.items.length` which infers there is a `item` array inside the received object.